# Is there a Collector that collects to an order-preserving Set?

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

`Collectors.toSet()` does not preserve order. I could use Lists instead, but I want to indicate that the resulting collection does not allow element duplication, which is exactly what `Set` interface is for.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists.  I know I needed one too, and I had to write my own.

Comment: Would `SortedSet` work? If not, custom is the way to go.

Comment: @AntonH No, I would prefer O(1) operations to O(log n).

Comment: [I posted that code,](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74572/collection-with-both-set-and-list-interface) it isn't exactly what you need but it might get you started.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can use `toCollection` and provide the concrete instance of the set you want. For example if you want to keep insertion order:

```
Set<MyClass> set = myStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

For example:

```
public class Test {    
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("b", "c", "a");

        Set<String> linkedSet = 
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

        Set<String> collectorToSet = 
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(linkedSet); //[b, c, a]
        System.out.println(collectorToSet); //[a, b, c]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I need, but I think Guava's `ImmutableSet` would be even better in my case. Any ideas on how I can make a collector that collects to `ImmutableSet`? Its instances are built with an `ImmutableSet.Builder` which is not a `Collection`, so I can't figure out how you would make a `Supplier` for `Collectors.toCollection()` in that case.

Comment: @Susei I'll try to look into it. An alternative would be to return an unmodifiable set. Ex: `Set<String> linkedSet = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));`
`linkedSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(linkedSet);`

Comment: @Susei The closest I found: `Set<String> set = list.stream().collect(
                ImmutableSet.Builder<String>::new,
                ImmutableSet.Builder<String>::add,
                (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.addAll(builder2.build())).build();` Not sure if it's a better approach by wrapping the resulting set with `Collections.unmodifiableSet`.

Comment: Here's a dedicated question since that's already off-topic (and for more rep for great answers, of course): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612165/how-would-you-make-a-java-util-stream-collector-that-collects-to-com-google-comm