# How would you make a java.util.stream.Collector that collects to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet?

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collectors

That seems too tricky for me since `ImmutableSet` instances are only built with `ImmutableSet.Builder` instances, which don't implement `Collection` so you can't just use `Collectors.toCollection(ImmutableSet::new)` or `Collectors.toCollection(ImmutableSet.Builder::new)`.

Comment: The implementation in the semicanonical JDK 8 fork of Guava is rather more simplistic: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.java?repo=jdk8-experimental#390

Comment: @LouisWasserman Shouldn't it be more efficient to use directly use [the builder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29018348/1587046) instead of `collectingAndThen` with `toCollection`?

Comment: Builders aren't really meant to be merged as in that example; it's not obvious that's preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is built into guava now,

[ImmutableSet#toImmutableSet](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#toImmutableSet--)

Use like,

```
something.stream().collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet())
```

Answer (score 5):

In fact, 3 months after :-), instead of defining a whole class for this, you can use `Collector.of`and wrap it in a simple utility method:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, Builder<T>, ImmutableSet<T>> immutableSetCollector() {
    return Collector.of(Builder<T>::new, Builder<T>::add, (s, r) -> s.addAll(r.build()), Builder<T>::build);
}
```

and then:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.Builder;
....

ImmutableSet<Point2D> set = 
    Stream.of(new Point2D(1, 2), ...).collect(immutableSetCollector());
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write custom collector by extending the `Collector` interface.

Here is a solid reference that talks about it good detail: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-writing-custom

Comment: Nice article, that's really almost exactly what I've come up with.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest that I found:

```
Set<String> set = list.stream().collect(ImmutableSet.Builder<String>::new, ImmutableSet.Builder<String>::add, (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.addAll(builder2.build())).build();
```

There is no method that takes append the elements of one builder into another builder, only an Iterable or an Iterator, so you cannot use a method reference for this one.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that writing a custom collector in this case is not such a difficult task as I imagined it to be:

```
package org.tendiwa.collections;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class ImmutableSetCollector<T> implements Collector<T, ImmutableSet.Builder<T>, ImmutableSet<T>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<ImmutableSet.Builder<T>> supplier() {
        return ImmutableSet.Builder::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<ImmutableSet.Builder<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (builder, element) -> builder.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<ImmutableSet.Builder<T>> combiner() {
        return (b1, b2) -> b1.addAll(b2.build());
    }

    @Override
    public Function<ImmutableSet.Builder<T>, ImmutableSet<T>> finisher() {
        return ImmutableSet.Builder::build;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return ImmutableSet.of();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImmutableSet<Point2D> set = Arrays.asList(
        new Point2D(1, 2),
        new Point2D(2, 4),
        new Point2D(3, 5),
        new Point2D(4, 4),
        new Point2D(5, 6),
        new Point2D(8, 6)
    ).stream().collect(new ImmutableSetCollector<>());
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Output:

```
[{1.0:2.0}, {2.0:4.0}, {3.0:5.0}, {4.0:4.0}, {5.0:6.0}, {8.0:6.0}]
```

Comment: The link I pasted has code reference that does more or less what you have.

Comment: @kuriouscoder Except that is says there in `charactersitics()` that the resulting collection is unordered, when `ImmutableSet` actually has the user-specified order as per its documentation: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html

Comment: Interesting. Isn't set unordered by default? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED

Comment: @kuriouscoder There is no constraint for Set ordering, so it is up to the implementation to decide. Characteristics.Unodrered just means that we can't rely on the set being ordered.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available out-of-the-box in the [guava-jdk8](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/guava-jdk8/) library (which I authored).

Comment: Please honor the full disclosure guidelines. Noting https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/

Comment: @Drew I didn't know this was an issue but sure I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well as some of us review about a 1000 a day, [this Reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/1816093) ... you have a high rep. Problem is with rep <100 spamming. Thanks. Keep on truckin'